# Showing a single column to multiple (n times)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a normal report like the below one,

```
Animal
Dog
Cat
Elephant
Tiger
Lion
Man
Panda
```

Which i want to do a break after n number of columns.

```
Animal      Animal
Dog         Cat
Elephant    Tiger
Lion        Man
Panda
```

I tried the page break which breaks  into a new page. Did some grouping etc.. still didn't work out. Is there a way in SSRS to work this out. I know how to do it via SQL, iam asking about doing it via SSRS.

**Edit:**
I have used the below query in SSRS.

```
SELECT 610 AS [Period],1 AS RowNumber
UNION
select 611, 2
UNION
select 612, 3
UNION
select 613, 4
UNION
select 614, 5
UNION
select 615, 6
UNION
select 616, 7
UNION
select 617, 8
```

I added a new Matrix table, then i added 'Period' field to the matrix table (Screenshot Num 1). In the column grouping expression. i have used the below expressions. One at a time

```
=Floor(Fields!RowNumber.Value / 3) and =Fields!RowNumber.Value Mod 3
```

but now it shows only 3 columns now.

What i have expected to see is (Screenshot Num 3) and what iam getting is (Screenshot Num 2).

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't use SSRS aggregate functions like `RowNumber` in grouping expressions or dataset calculated fields. So you would need to add a number to your rows in the SQL. I would recommend using `ROW_NUMBER` for this. You could also use a `RANK` function. You don't have to partition by anything, just give it something to sort by and you're good to go.

Then in the report, you can use a column grouping expression like this to get 5 rows per column:

```
=Floor(Fields!RowNumber.Value / 5)
```

To use a specific number of columns you could use an expression like this:

```
=Fields!RowNumber.Value Mod 5
```

Comment: Hi Steven, Please see the edited section in main question to see my findings. Can you take a look at this please?